# How to get recent data from bigtable?

Tags: python, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I need to get 50 latest data (based on timestamp) from BigTable.

I get the data using `read_row` and filter using `CellsRowLimitFilter(50)`. But it didn't return the latest data. It seems the data didn't sorted based on timestamp? how to get the latest data?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was on the schema. It wasn't designed for timeseries data. I should have create the rowkey with `id#reverse_timestamp` and the data will be sorted from the latest. Now I can use `CellsRowLimitFilter(50)` and get 50 latest data.

Comment: You can read by 'cell' timestamp as well. If you don't necessarily want the 'latest' from the   'event time'. This comes handy in cases where you want to read the latest written records from the table.
https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setTimeRange-long-long-

Comment: @Hana how can we generate reverse_timestamp? Doesn't bigtable store records in sorted by timestamp by default? how does reverse timestamp provide additional help to get recent record?

Answer (score 2):

All data(cells) related to Bigtable row keys are stored per timestamps providing a record of how the stored data has been altered over time. the method that you are using `CellsRowLimitFilter(50)` [will return the first N cells of the row](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigtable/latest/row-filters.html#google.cloud.bigtable.row_filters.CellsRowLimitFilter), while what you want is the latest not the first so you should use `CellsColumnLimitFilter(50)` 
[which will return only the most recent N cells within each column](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigtable/latest/row-filters.html#google.cloud.bigtable.row_filters.CellsColumnLimitFilter).